# How to create a search that will not accept a certain character

Tags: c#, search

I am trying to create a search that when the user searches for something with a semi colon will return with an error.  This is what I have so far any improvements to the code would be great as well!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Assignment1
{
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void SUBMIT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 


        {
            string sConnection = "Data Source=labsql;Integrated Security=True;database=master";
            SqlConnection dbConn;
            dbConn = new SqlConnection(sConnection);
            dbConn.Open();

            string sql = "SELECT * FROM you_found_the_easter_egg WHERE Message LIKE '%" + DataInputBox.Text + "%' OR IsThisFunnyToJeff LIKE '%" + DataInputBox.Text + "%' OR George LIKE '%" + DataInputBox.Text + "%';";
            SqlCommand dbCmd = new SqlCommand(sql);
            dbCmd.Connection = dbConn;

            SqlDataReader reader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())

            reader.Close();
            dbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            dbConn.Close();
        }

        }

    }
}
```

Also, in terms of presenting the results what should I use for that?  Would a list box be the easiest way to present the results?

Comment: [holy grail, someone actually uses raw query](http://www.commitstrip.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Strip-Brutal-peur-de-rien-englishenglish.jpg). first thing you should do is properly validate and escape the `DataInputBox.Text`. Validating can be done using regex.. and you can put your restriction there. but seriously, avoid using raw queries at all cost -- use [EntityFramework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/) or [NHibernate](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NHibernate/) whenever possible.

Comment: you need to use a parametrized query. never inject user input into query text. To return an error on semicolon, you need not actually execute the query. just use `DataInputBox.Text.Contains(";")`. As for where the results should go, we cannot tell unless you desribe what you expect. Which columns are selected?

Comment: There are three columns selected, and where would I put "DataInputBox.Text.Contains(";")" Im very new to this and I dont quite get how that would cause the search to say error? Basically Im trying to search this database for a term and have it return all of the times it was mentioned.  And reject the search if it includes a semicolon.

Comment: What error you are getting? `while (reader.Read())` doesn't have any body. `dbCmd.ExecuteReader` and `dbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery` why two times executing the same command?

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson your code is wide open for SQL injection attacks.  You wont have to worry about filtering out a `;` character if you parameterize your query.

Answer (score 0):

## Try using the valid chars attribute to specify in the textbox the characters you want to accept

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/ajax-control-toolkit/filteredtextbox/allowing-only-certain-characters-in-a-text-box-cs

```
<ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="ftbe" runat="server"
 TargetControlID="TextBox1" ValidChars="1234567890"/>
```